# Create object with sub-objects up to the n-th level

Tags: javascript

I have an object called **`MyObject`** and a method called **`createEntry()`** which aims to create a new property for **`MyObject`** and sub-properties for the property or just skip it altogether if it already exists.

**My code:**

```
var MyObject = {
    createEntry: function (val1, val2, val3, val4) {
        this[val1] = this[val1] || {};
        this[val1][val2] = this[val1][val2] || {};
        this[val1][val2][val3] = val4;
    }
};

MyObject.createEntry("val1", "val2", "val3", "val4");
```

As shown in the above function, I'm trying to create a new sub-object for each argument of the method **`createEntry()`** except for the last two, where **`val3`** is a **`property`** or **`method`** and **`val4`** is its value.

With my method in its current state, I can only reach up to level 3 with its subsequent ones requiring longer and longer code. I assume the above can be achieved with a **`while`** loop, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

**Question:** How can I create unlimited sub-objects based on the number of arguments passed on the above function in a tree fashion that looks like the following:

```
var MyObject = {
   val1: {
      val2 {
         val3: val4
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oriol gave a fantastic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39521925/6313073), but his function, due to the way it's built, is not really useful as it returns a new object instead of modifying **`MyObject`**.

So, in order to actually modify **`MyObject`**, instead of the first **`return`**, we have to do something else that will modify **`MyObject`** without overwriting it.

To do just that, a function that expands the **`MyObject`** must be built:

```
expand: function (object) {
   for (var key in object) if (!!object[key]) {
      if (key in this) throw new Error("`" + key + "` already exists.");
      else this[key] = object[key];
   }
}
```

Then, all we have to do is to use @Oriol's answer without the first **`return`** statement as an argument to **`expand()`**:

```
createEntry: function () {
   this.expand([].reduceRight.call(arguments, function(previous, current) {
      return {[current]: previous};
   }));
}
```

**Full code:**

```js
var MyObject = {
  createEntry: function() {
    this.expand([].reduceRight.call(arguments, function(previous, current) {
      return {
        [current]: previous
      };
    }));
  },
  expand: function(object) {
    for (var key in object)
      if (!!object[key]) {
        if (key in this) throw new Error("`" + key + "` already exists.");
        else this[key] = object[key];
      }
  }
};

MyObject.createEntry("val1", "val2", "val3", "val4");
console.log(MyObject);
```

Thanks to everyone for the help!

Answer (score 4):

[`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) seems perfect for this:

```js
function createEntry(...args) {
  return args.reduceRight(function(prev, curr) {
    return {[curr]: prev};
  });
}
console.log(createEntry("val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"));
```

Comment: Awesome, I upvoted, but the spread operator is ES6... I love the older browsers too :)

Comment: @AngelPolitis Then use `[].reduceRight.call(arguments,`

Answer (score 1):

Well, when creating unlimited sub-objects using parameters, I'd iterate each parameter, having the last object I entered as reference. This code is enough to understand.

Note: `Object.assign` is a new browser implementation, but it has [polyfills](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) already. I use this method to concatenate object with object when a entry name already exists in a object

```
Object['prototype']['createEntries'] = function() {
    /* store last object location */
    var lastObj = this

    /**
     * Note: each argument is a object that specify the following properties -->
     * inner : the entry object
     * *name : the entry property name
     */

    for (var i = 0, arg, existent, len = arguments.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if (typeof (arg = arguments[i]) === 'object' && (typeof arg.inner === 'object' ? true : arg.inner = {} ))
            /* create new entry/keep existent entry and reserve it in lastObj */
            lastObj = (typeof (existent = lastObj[arg.name]) === 'object' ?
                    lastObj[arg.name] = Object.assign(existent, arg.inner) :
                    lastObj[arg.name] = arg.inner)
    }

    return this
}
```

Then this is a basic usage

```
({}).createEntries({
    name: "val1"
}, {
    name: "val2"
})
/* {
       val1: {
            val2: {
            }
       }
   }
*/
```

I hope this is what you want

Comment: Hey @TheProHands, thanks for the answer. The names 'Object', 'val1', 'val2' etc are used in this example in an attempt to create a minimal piece of code, so don't worry about conflicts in my code. Now coming to your answer, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think this is the way to go. Each sub-object will have a specified name and not some abstract 'val123' etc and also I don't see how the last two arguments are in that format: **`val3`: val4**. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @AngelPolitis Ah! You need to specify this in parameters. I'll update it

Comment: I corrected a typo inside the code. If you prefer the normal style of code, I can update it to make more legible. Yea, I tested it. Have you checked it again?

Comment: I'm checking it out now... Ok, one thing that's bugging me about trying to understand your code is why you attach the **`createEntry()`** method to the native Object and not **`MyObject`**...

Comment: Also, why is **`createEntry()`** taking an object as an argument. You have heavily modified the initial code. Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @AngelPolitis You can still implement the same function inside `createEntry` function since `this` refers to your **`Object`**

Comment: Polluting `Object.prototype` is dangerous.

Comment: @Oriol Yes, when making libraries.